# Python programs freeze when run simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, opencv, pyaudio

I have written 2 separate codes- one for transfer of audio simultaneously between two systems using sockets and pyaudio and the other for transfer of video between two systems using sockets and opencv2.
Both codes when executed individually work fine while when I execute them simultaneously(so as to simulate a video chat), both of them freeze and I have to force close the terminals.

Is it possible that they hang because several threads(around 10) are running simultaneously? How can I prevent it?

Comment: It's unlikely that your machine can't handle 10 concurrent threads. My first thought is that the sockets may be attempting to use the same port?

Comment: No, I made sure they are using different ports.

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: are you storing the frames in some sort of list ? please update the question with some code and if you see any errors in the terminal